# How to capture network packets that use SS7 protocol using Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, network-protocols, packet-analyzer, gsm

Since SS7 protocol stack is used in GSM mobile telephony network, we can't get the packets of SS7 protocols using Wireshark in Windows Computer and browsing in a web browser like Google chrome.

So how can one get packets which have SS7 protocol in Wireshark? Is it even possible?

I mean what kind of activity should I perform (which Wireshark is running and capturing packets) which will result in packets (captured by Wireshark) which use SS7 protocols?

Comment: What's the nature of the physical network this is running on, and how do you expect that there is actually SS7 traffic there?

Comment: @EEAA That's what I am asking. What do I do to get some SS7 traffic? I don't think there is any SS7 traffic. It's normal internet, and I have captured packets many times and haven't seen any SS7 traffic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the ability to perform packet captures within a telco network, you will never see SS7 traffic. For GSM, SS7 usage would be used over the mobile RF network, which not only is encrypted, but is transmitted via mechanisms you don't have access to in the first place.

If you need to examine SS7, I would recommend standing up an Asterisk server. Asterisk [has some level of SS7](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SS7) support, and you may be able to mock up some SS7 transmissions. Whether or not you can coax it to use ethernet for SS7, though, is another matter...